# How does StackOverflow's 'tags' textbox autocomplete work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, textbox, autocomplete

I know they're using a jQuery plugin, but I can't seem to find which one they used. In particular, what I'm looking for is autocomplete with exactly the same functionality as SO's autocomplete, where it will perform an AJAX command with each new word typed in and allow you to select one from a dropdown.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set up jQuery autocomplete like stackoverflow's input field tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519107/set-up-jquery-autocomplete-like-stackoverflows-input-field-tags)

Comment: @Dave - I asked this question 3 months before the question you linked was asked, so I would argue that that question is a duplicate of this one - it just happened to be more popular. ;)

Comment: Fair point. The chosen answer for the other question is more comprehensive, though.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Note that the tag editor [has been completely re-written now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100669/feedback-wanted-improved-tag-editor), and no longer resembles the original, simple text box w/ suggestion drop-down that adorned the site for nearly three years.

If you're interested in the new form, see this Meta question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102510/can-i-use-the-tag-textbox-script

[Autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete) is the plugin used originally, albeit with various tweaks and customizations made to it over the years.

Answer (score 2):

You might also like this one:

- http://code.google.com/p/jquery-autocomplete/

Read the history here: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-autocomplete/wiki/History

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [SO_Tag](http://www.iog3.com/322/so_tag-tagging-system-based-on-stackoverflows-tag-search/), a tagging system based on StackOverflows tagging system.

And [Github](https://github.com/iog3/SOTag).