# jQuery autocomplete tagging plug-in like StackOverflow's input tags?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, tags

What solutions accomplish the same auto-completion that SO uses for entering tags?

There are plugins that can handle one word but I haven't seen any that handle multiple words.

Comment: Voting to close as tool rec.

Comment: I've created the best - https://github.com/yairEO/tagify

Comment: @vsync Added it to the list in the first answer. Unfortunately can't link directly to codepen.io due to not having any code in the answer

Comment: @JoePhilllips - maybe it will accept google URL shortened ones

Comment: @JoePhilllips - My plugin is better than the best one on the top of the list, and deserves to be on the top and I have good selling points for that. currently the top one on the list is bloated (x4 than mine), uses extra input element (bad for form serialization) and does not support commas or pasting tags with them. it does offer some features which are nice but unneeded for most cases. `autocomplete` should be used desperately IMHO

Comment: @vsync welp, yours only has a few days under its belt. I reorganized the list a bit to honor the ones that are still available, recently updated, focused, and mentioned. Yours made it to #4

Comment: What an honor :) it's not wine you know, in code usually the newer the better. A person won't bother coding a newer version of something unless it is better and the code has learned from the mistakes of the older ones and tried to out-smart them :)

Answer (score 777, accepted):

In order of activity, demos/examples available, and simplicity:

- ([demo](https://github.com/yairEO/tagify#demo-page)) https://github.com/yairEO/tagify
- ([demo](https://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/examples.html)) https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it
- ([demo](http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/)) https://ioncache.github.io/Tag-Handler/
- ([demo](http://textextjs.com/)) http://textextjs.com/
- ([demo](http://tagedit.webwork-albrecht.de/playground.html)) https://github.com/webworka/Tagedit
- ([demo](http://documentcloud.github.com/visualsearch/#demo)) https://github.com/documentcloud/visualsearch/
- ([demo](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#multiple-select)) http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ (this isn't really a tagging plugin)
- (demo?) http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/
- (demo?) http://jcesar.artelogico.com/jquery-tagselector/
- (demo?) http://remysharp.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/12/tagging.php
- (demo?) http://pietschsoft.com/post/2011/09/09/Tag-Editor-Field-using-jQuery-similar-to-StackOverflow.aspx

Related:

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100669/feedback-wanted-improved-tag-editor

Comment: On IE9 it is giving "Line: 18
Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'tagit'"

Comment: @raghav-khunger on IE the keyword "const" is not supported for javascript, hense the error. Check this out [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130396/are-there-constants-in-javascript)

Comment: Anyone looking for the most up to date version, documentation and more extensive examples of this amazing plugin should go here and fork away: https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it

Comment: We just released Bootstrap Tokenfield. It's main focus is on copy-paste, keyboard and editability support. http://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/

Comment: Anyone who can recommend a good one with knockout.JS?

Comment: Here's another good one:  http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/     I'd add it as an answer, but that would clearly be "unconstructive".

Comment: Tag-it is very good for jquery autocomplete integration.

Comment: selectize.js 6500+ stars at github. worth checking. https://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/

Comment: I am looking for one with autocomplete function and we can disable duplicate check, which one is good? Some of them always have duplicate check but it is not possible to disable this function.

Comment: update: I think magicsuggest  is the best option now.

Comment: Your second others link is broken.

Comment: @Felipe Schenone  **Tag-It** is good , but i have a problem when i want to post the selected tags `ID` using a form, users are facing same issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997450/jquery-tag-it-using-a-value-and-label-object-list), i want to set tag id's in hidden field and use it later during post, any good solution or other plugin ?

Comment: tag-it is overrated. Requiring jquery for a simple tag system is too much, but requiring as well jQuery UI and jquery UI CSS is just mad nowadays. Not worth it.

Comment: @Alvaro totally agree, so mad about the deps will absolutely not use tag-it. Were you able to find a similar one in vanilla?

Comment: @scniro I ended up using [jquery.tagsinput](https://github.com/xoxco/jQuery-Tags-Input) because I do not mind using jQuery which is already being used in my project. I just though it was mad to ask for jquery UI and CSS.

Comment: Tag-It has issues, especially when changing read-write access (dynamically, client-side).

Comment: Fore some reason I am not allowed using jQuery, is there any solution just css/js?

Comment: *Select2* Was a much better option for me. Try it before tag-it

Comment: how about this library https://github.com/sniperwolf/taggingJS ? Is it better than above mentioned libraries?

Comment: I quite like tagify. It seems to be the most lightweight and easiest to configure. Only thing I don't like about it is the strange markup.

Comment: None of them worked for me. I am looking a tag feature like an input textbox and all the selected tags should be displayed below the input textbox, Not inside the textbox. If you have any solution, kindly share with me. Thanks.

Comment: As of 2022, https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it doesn't seem to be working or maintained anymore

Answer (score 63):

**Bootstrap:** If you are using Bootstrap. This is a really good one: [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/)

Also, [TokenInput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/) is an interesting one. First, it does not depend on jQuery-UI, second its config is very smooth.

The only issue I had it does not support free-tagging natively. So, I have to return the query-string back to client as a part of response JSON.

---

As @culithay mentioned in the comment, TokenInput supports a lot of features to customize. And highlight of some feature that the others don't have:

- tokenLimit: The maximum number of results allowed to be selected by the user. Use null to allow unlimited selections
- minChars: The minimum number of characters the user must enter before a search is performed.
- queryParam: The name of the query param which you expect to contain the search term on the server-side

Thanks culithay for the input.

Comment: TokenInput looks like it's exactly what I've been looking for: user types some stuff in, performs a search on the server, user can select a searched for element, rinse and repeat.

Comment: TokenInput supports a lot of features to customize. And I highlight some feature that the others don't have.
- tokenLimit: The maximum number of results allowed to be selected by the user. Use null to allow unlimited selections
- minChars: The minimum number of characters the user must enter before a search is performed.
- queryParam: The name of the query param which you expect to contain the search term on the server-side

Comment: How to add new free tags with it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28656977/select2-event-for-creating-a-new-tag Hard :-(

Comment: Good one. Not supporting free-tagging is not a big issue, since it can be easily overcome.

Answer (score 8):

This originally answered a supplemental question about the wisdom of downloading jQuery versus accessing it via a CDN, which is no longer present...

To answer the thing about Google. I have moved over to accessing JQuery and most other of these sorts of libraries via the corresponding CDN in my sites.

As more people do this means that it's more likely to be cached on user's machines, so my vote goes for good idea.

In the five years since I first offered this, it has become common wisdom.

Comment: We roll this out as part of our default templates as well. Google can serve this code zipped and out of a CDN faster than us, plus if there's even a 2% chance that a visitor has this cached it's better than no chance at all.

Comment: How is this the answer to the original question?

Comment: The last part 'Also,...' asks whether linking to the Google version is a good or bad idea, and my answer is that it is an increasingly good idea.

Comment: @Derek I don't think I had any other acceptable answers when I originally asked it. That has since changed.

Answer (score 5):

Another excellent plugin can be found at https://documentcloud.github.io/visualsearch/

Answer (score 2):

Check this plugin:

- [source](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it)
- [basic demo](http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it)
- [more examples](http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it/examples.html)

How to use AJAX for loading the tags https://stackoverflow.com/a/7662534/1078027

Comment: The demo page is dead here too

Answer (score 1):

We just open-sourced this jquery plug-in [Github: tactivos/jquery-sew](https://github.com/tactivos/jquery-sew).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid (and downvoted) if the linked page changes. See [How To Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) for why it is important.

Comment: The demo page is dead.

Comment: Agree with @EdwardOlamisan. The demo page results in HTTP code 403.