# Stackoverflow's Interesting Tags Implementation

Tags: jquery

I can't seem to find any resources relating to the implementation of SO's interesting tags javascript implementation, where adding tags happens on the client-side, and you can delete tags on the client-side also.  It's just I'm looking for a way to select multiple entities for use in a query, without using a multi-select list (combo box?).  The tag-style format is very useful.  This is also similar to Facebook's messaging where you can specify multiple recipients.

Any pointers?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519107/how-can-i-set-up-jquery-autocomplete-like-stackoverflows-tags-input-field

Comment: Similar, but it doesn't support the features I require really.  I use autocompleter plugin already, and it doesn't do this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a nice new jQuery Plugin which will even place an image around each tag and add a remove button.

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/tag-it

[image]

Comment: Amazingly simple and effective plugin

Comment: is there a react component?

Comment: I had a look at both react-select and tag-it, neither of them support click to edit a selected tag.