# Tag suggestion plugin ala Stackoverflow tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tags, autosuggest

I love the way StackOverflow handles tags. Is there any jQuery plugin that would duplicate the behavior?

I found this [jQuery Tag Suggest](http://remysharp.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/12/tagging.php) but it's not near as good.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you don't end up finding one, you could write your own and the masses would love you for it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set up jQuery autocomplete like stackoverflow's input field tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519107/set-up-jquery-autocomplete-like-stackoverflows-input-field-tags)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery UI Autocomplete widget has something very similar now worth checking out (if you're already using [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/home)): the [Autocomplete multiple values example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple).

Comment: +1 This would duplicate, almost exactly, SO's tag suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another awesome example of how to do it using Rails and jQuery UI Autocomplete:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/102-auto-complete-association-revised