# Form tag-like inputs

Tags: html, css, forms

I have no idea what this is even called so not sure where to start, hoping you all are able to point me in the right direction. I am trying to create something like this:

[image: Input Tags]

The idea being that when a user types something in and then separates with a comma, their input into this form field will turn into a little tag-like box that they can then delete with the x.

Any ideas on where to start?

Thanks!

Comment: Its probably a JQuery plugin. You can get it for your application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tag suggestion plugin ala Stackoverflow tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877136/tag-suggestion-plugin-ala-stackoverflow-tags)

Comment: Both of these answers are actually for drop downs, as I mentioned in the question, I am looking for the tag to show up as a user types in content that will not be pre-stored (as in a select field)

Comment: The answers below should be a good starting point, which is what you were asking for. You will probably have to dig into the code and find the relevant parts yourself.

Comment: Tagging plugins are also a good starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/9tzb4/

HTML:

```
<form>
  Tags:
  <div class="tag_field">
    <input type="text">  
    <input type="hidden" name="tags">
  </div>

  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

CSS:

```
.tag_buttons {
  position: absolute;  
}

.tag_buttons div {
  display:inline-block;
  margin: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  padding: 1px;
}

.tag_field input[type=text] {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #666;

}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".tag_field").each(function() {
  var buttons = $("<div/>");
  var input = $(this).find("input[type=text]");
  var output = $(this).find("input[type=hidden]");

  var update_padding = function() {
    input.css("padding-left", buttons.width() + 2);
  };       
  setInterval(update_padding, 300);

  $(this).prepend(buttons);
  buttons.addClass("tag_buttons");
  buttons.css({ left: input.offset().left + 1,
                top: input.offset().top + 2 });
  input.bind("keyup change paste", function() {
    var i = input.val().indexOf(",");
    if (i >= 0) {
      var new_tag = input.val().substr(0, i);
      input.val(input.val().substr(i+1));
      buttons.append("<div id='button'><span class='value'>"+new_tag+"</span> <span class='close'>(x)</span></div>");
    }
  });

  var form = $(this).closest("form");
  if (form.length > 0) {
    form.submit(function() {
      var v = [];
      form.find(".tag_buttons div").each(function() {
        v.push($(this).find(".value").html());      
      });

      output.val(v.join(","));
      return false;
    });          
  }

});
$(document).on("click", ".tag_buttons span.close", {}, function(e) {
  $(e.target).closest("div").detach();      
});
```

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for. Thanks Riateche!

Comment: Works for me in Safari 5.1.7 (win). How exactly does it not work?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the amazing [jQuery chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/), which - among other things - does exactly what you're looking for.

[select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/#tags) is a similar plugin, and it also allows you to add your own tags (as well as use an AJAX source).

---

**Update** from the `select2` docs:

> Note that when tagging is enabled the user can select from pre-existing tags or **create a new tag** by picking the first choice which is what the user has typed into the search box so far.

Comment: This would be perfect if I already had the inputs. I am looking for this functionality when a user types in any content, not just pre-entered content.

Comment: @KevinZ - What do you mean by "pre-entered content"? Do you mean your predefined tags? Like I said, `select2` allows the user to create their own tags.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out. http://davidwalsh.name/dw-content/jquery-chosen.php This is the things I guess will perfectly suite your application.

Comment: This would be perfect if I already had the inputs. I am looking for this functionality when a user types in any content, not just pre-entered content.

Comment: @KevinZ do one thing. Just try out typing something on the box. It pre populates things with the  default values. Check out there must be some option for this thing what you are looking for.I too will do the same and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

You may find the [jQuery Tags Input Library](http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/) helpful. It gives you something like this

[image]