# jQuery Tag selector

Tags: php, jquery

I'm looking to add Tag function bar like stackoverflow has to type in tags when subbmiting a question to add to my website. The question is there a nickname for them, I cannot pull them up on Google for some reason. Thank you

Comment: exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869008/stack-overflow-style-tagging-system-in-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one looks like it could work for you: http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/