# Style strings separated by spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a form where I can edit event information for a calendar.  These specific events run every single week, but one of the form fields is for "days off" where you can enter days where the event doesn't run.  using mysql and php, any current days off will be displayed in a textarea field, separated by spaces.  You will also be able to put in more days off by typing in a date and making spaces.  I would like to be able to style each date just like right here on stack overflow when you ask a new question and put in the tags.  After you type in a tag, it gets surrounded by a box, turns blue, and gets an x for deleting it.  This is what I want.
Here's a link to a screenshot of what I want it to look like.
http://www.uvm.edu/~sass/screenshot.jpg

Comment: Good luck. What have you tried? Did you have a look at how the tags work here on SO? They are NOT inside a textarea / input field.

Comment: I've heard some autocomplete plugins do what I want, but I really don't want autocomplete where you have to choose from a list.  I simply want to have it style my entries after every space.  I looked at the SO one, but it seemed like a lot more going on than I want.  I wanted to keep it simple so it's easy to use the submitted data.

Comment: Plus I don't understand it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have found a solution by digging around the internet.
[Stack Overflow style tagging system in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869008/stack-overflow-style-tagging-system-in-jquery) (view the second answer)

Someone created exactly what I want.  The results are stored in a hidden field as a comma separated list so I can easily explode it into an array for use with my database, and it formats the inputs nicely with css.  I modified the look with css and changed the accepted formats to work with dates and here is the result.

http://www.uvm.edu/~sass/screenshot.png

Comment: The Tagit jquery plugin also does what I want and works a lot better.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how it works with dates and formatting them, but as for displaying in such style I've been using [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) component. If you can add parsing or create valid list of dates it should give you the correct result.

Comment: hmm, it seem like autotokenization is what I want, but I can't really create lists for every date for the next 30 years.  I'm going to keep digging.