# plugin to separate tags (like the stackoverflow's input tags interface)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, autocomplete

I'm looking for a plugin or simple script that behaves like [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com)'s *tags* input interface.

In particular I need to separate the single words (tags) that people write.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I set up JQuery autocomplete like Stackoverflow's tags input field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519107/how-can-i-set-up-jquery-autocomplete-like-stackoverflows-tags-input-field)

Comment: Thank me later - https://github.com/yairEO/tagify

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There are **plenty**:

1. <strike>http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin</strike> (**broken link** [github link](https://github.com/drewwilson/AutoSuggest))
2. http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/
3. <strike>http://plugins.jquery.com/project/tag-it</strike> (**broken link** [github link](http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/))
4. <strike>http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquerytag</strike> (**broken link**)

**If you are looking for a styled and ready solution, I'd recommend the first option.**

If you are looking for a more flexible and complete solution, the second solution is probably a good fit.

Comment: +1 for the first link, since I found it surprisingly difficult to find a good solution through Google.

Comment: I tried plenty of scripts, it took one day to find the simple one that does only read tags from an existing array (no JSON), here you go: https://github.com/bastianallgeier/tags

Comment: https://github.com/tovic/tags-input-beautifier ← you could also set predefined values from the original input value and split it with comma, so that it becomes array, e.g. `{values:input.value.split(', ')}`

Comment: You can add [Tagify](https://github.com/yairEO/tagify) to the list

Answer (score 12):

Here are a few jQuery plugins that do what you want to do:

- [bootstrap.TagManager](http://plugins.jquery.com/bootstrap.TagManager/) ([GitHub](https://github.com/max-favilli/tagmanager), [Demo](http://welldonethings.com/tags/manager))
- [Bootstrap Tags Input](http://plugins.jquery.com/bootstrap-tagsinput/) ([GitHub](http://github.com/TimSchlechter/bootstrap-tagsinput), [Demo](http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/))
- [TagTagger.js](http://plugins.jquery.com/TagTagger/) ([GitHub](http://github.com/exexzian/TagTagger.js), [Demo](http://exexzian.github.io/TagTagger.js/demo/taggerDemo.html))
- [Tagtacular](http://plugins.jquery.com/tagtacular/) ([GitHub](http://github.com/burnsbert/tagtacular), [Demo](http://gototech.com/tagtacular))

Answer (score 3):

Here is another jQuery plugin which does the same:
http://textextjs.com/

Answer (score 2):

Autocomplete + tags => http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/

[demo](http://jquery.bassistance.de/autocomplete/demo/)