# How to style the values in a textfield using CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can i style the values that in a textfield, for example: if if i have the values `Science, Mathematics` in a textfield. In place of having a comma separating them, i would want to display these subjects in boxes or something. Like adding tags to a questing in stackoverflow!

Comment: possible duplicate of [plugin to separate tags (like the stackoverflow's input tags interface)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031162/plugin-to-separate-tags-like-the-stackoverflows-input-tags-interface)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The textbox you *see* on stackoverflow, isn't a textbox.

Its most probably a `div` with a border, with `span` tags for each tag. Then there is a `textbox` (without borders) floated next to it.

This gives the appearance of the tags actually being inside the textbox, when they're not.

When you click <kbd>space</kbd>, this is then adding a new record to the tags.

See this jQuery plugin for an example:

http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with CSS alone.  You will have to use some sort of javascript/jquery Plugin to accomplish this task.

Here is one I've used. It is pretty good:

http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

Comment: Any suggestions, if you are aware of any?

Comment: Look at the multiple select option.

Answer (score 0):

What is a *textfield*? Is it `<textarea>`? You cannot style distinct textual elements in it as it is not a container. Check out JavaScript rich-text editors out there if you need text formatting/coloring inside an editable field. [FCKEditor](http://drupal.org/project/fckeditor) is one example.

Comment: no its a normal textfield! i simply want to style it like the way tags are generally styled

Comment: Same deal here. You might want to give `contenteditable` a try (google it) but folks out there say it's extremely hard to use and unstable.