# How to implement a Tag Bar in javascript / css

Tags: javascript, html, css, tags

I'm trying to implement a search bar for a web page having basically the same properties of the `Tag bar` appearing when you ask questions on Stack overflow:

[image]

It should have the following properties:

- Allow the user to directly type in it.
- Pull up `entries` with same letters as the user is typing.
- Allow to delete an entry by either deleting on keyboard or pressing on inserted elements.

I'm interested in understanding the underlying structure of such an element and how to setup listeners and functions that call each other, not simply the code. Could anyone please help me figure out the skeleton of the functions I need to implement?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031162/plugin-to-separate-tags-like-the-stackoverflows-input-tags-interface

Comment: jQuery UI Autocomplete, http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Answer (score 1):

Besides just using a jQuery UI plugin, the simplest way to do it would be with a text input box and a ul. You can use jQuery (or something else depending on if you are using a framework) to listen to any change in the input box.

At that point you have a choice depending on the rest of your app: The filtering can happen in the front end or the backend. Because databases tend to be fairly quick, it might make sense to filter within it if you have a very large set of data. Otherwise, you could just grab the entire list and use JS to filter it.

Either way, have a callback occur on that change that initiates the filtering and then renders the results into the ul.