# jQuery Tag-it plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, tags, tag-it

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Trying to get tag-it to work with an AJAX call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938802/trying-to-get-tag-it-to-work-with-an-ajax-call)

How can I get tags from the database for autocomplete.

I thing I can handle the php part by myself :)

This is the minimal code for the autocomplete feature and I really don't get it how to post the tag to php.

```
$(function(){
    $('#tags').tagit({
        availableTags: ['c++', 'java', 'php', 'coldfusion', 'javascript', 'asp', 'ruby', 'python', 'c', 'scala', 'groovy', 'haskell', 'perl', 'erlang', 'apl', 'cobol', 'go', 'lua']
    });
});
```

you can find the full code here:
http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it/css/jquery.tagit.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to fill in availableTags variable with available tags from the database?
You can simply do

```
<?php
echo "'$tag1', ";
echo "'$tag2', ";
...
?>
```

between `[` and `]`

Or you can of course get your data with `$.ajax()` or `$.get()`
For example:

```
$.get('available.php', function(data) {
console.dir(data);
});
```

In case you are doing autocomplete, you can have your PHP script respond with available tags by given entry, for example:

```
<?php
$response = Array();
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
if (strpos($tag, $entry) !== false) $response[] = $tag;
}

now echo $response array as json or xml or whatever you want
?>
```

On the JavaScript part you would invoke on each keypress a call similar to this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "available.php",
  data: "entry="+ $('input[name=entry]').val(),
}).done(function( data) {
  // invoke your TagIt plugin with data but first decode it
});
```

Comment: the first solution would echo all tags from the database...there are over 2000 tags in the database.

the second code...would that work like a standard search?

Comment: I've updated the answer, thebasdfasd

Comment: i don't get it really,
I just have this code:
<script>
    $(function(){
     $('#tags').tagit();
    });
    </script>
    <ul id="tags"></ul>

so, how should it look like when all is done?

Comment: Does this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938802/trying-to-get-tag-it-to-work-with-an-ajax-call help ?

Comment: I am glad that helped, however next time use Google as I've entered "tagit ajax stackoverflow" and the first result was that link :)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
var availableTags = <?php echo json_encode($availableTags); ?>;
```

Here `$availableTags` is a PHP array that you can create with

```
$availableTags = array();
```

Comment: Not a good idea at all because there could be thousands of tags in the database and the question is already solved here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938802/trying-to-get-tag-it-to-work-with-an-ajax-call

Comment: Yes that is the whole point, you get all the tags. Or is it that there needs to be a limit for the number of tags? And of course you can use array_unique to get the unique tags, its more faster to retrieve results than getting the tags from a php file.

Comment: As I mentioned, there are thousands of UNIQUE tags in the database...It would be very slow to get them all at once and you just need a couple for autocomplete. Got it?

Comment: Oh so you mean to keep adding tags one-by-one manually. Then that would work. I dont think google would want to do that.