# jQuery TagIt (autocomplete) Fetching JSON list via AJAX

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete

This is a question based on: [Trying to get tag-it to work with an AJAX call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938802/trying-to-get-tag-it-to-work-with-an-ajax-call)

However the above just creates an error message of 'this.source is not a function' for me.

I am trying to get this json list to appear as the tag source for tagit via ajax. Code below:

```
// Tagit
$("#tags").tagit({      
    tagSource: function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/admin/ajax.php?q=fetch_all_tags",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                return data;
            }
        });
    }       
});
```

The ajax call returns:

```
{"4":"php","2":"html","3":"css"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error was caused by me using an old version of tag it. If you get the same error make sure you are using the newest version of tagit

Answer (score 19):

Check out [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/MHVas/15/) may help you

```
$("#mytags").tagit({
    autocomplete: {
        source: function( request, response ) {
            /*call api*/
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @rjdmello  Your code snippet is working perfectly and it's the best answer here.

Answer (score 4):

The autocomplete.source should be overridden if you want to use custom autocompletion sources, like an Ajax / XHR response.

For example:

```
$("#myTags").tagit({
    autocomplete: {
       delay: 0,
       minLength: 2,
       source : 'your data response'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably should use something like that for success handler:

```
success: function (categoriesList) {
    response($.map(categoriesList, function (category) {
        return {
            label: category.Name + " (ID: " + category.ID + ")",
            value: category.Name
        };
    }));
}
```

I'm displaying categories objects which have ID and Name properties.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you can overwrite the autocomplete method from jquery UI :

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

$('.tags ul').tagit({

    itemName: 'question',
    fieldName: 'tags',
    removeConfirmation: true,
    //availableTags: ["c++", "java", "php", "javascript", "ruby", "python", "c"]
    allowSpaces: true,
    // tagSource: ['foo', 'bar']
    tagSource: function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/autocomplete_tags.json",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                term: 'ruby'
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                return data;
            }

        });
    },
    autocomplete: {
        delay: 0,
        minLength: 2,
        source: this.tagSource()
    }
});
```

Comment: not working for me `this.tagSource is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

If you are newbie like me and don't understand the above solution here's a complete code

```
    $("#mySingleFieldTags").tagit({
      autocomplete: {
        source: function( request, response ) {
          console.log(request);
          $.ajax({
                url: "/autocomplete",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                  'search':request.term
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (category) {
                      return {
                          label: category.name,
                        
                      };
                  }));
                }
            });
          }
      }
    });
```