# Jquery Tag it in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, tag-it

I am using jQuery UI widget [Tag it](http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/). Code which i am using is working fine but all the Tag values visible on the browser.

Code I am using is below

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
      <script src="../JavaScript/tag-it.js"></script>
    <link href="../CSS/tagit.ui-zendesk.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../CSS/jquery.tagit.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script>
        $(function(){
           var sampleTags = [<%# this.SuggestionList %>];
            //var sampleTags = ['c++', 'java', 'php', 'coldfusion', 'javascript', 'asp', 'ruby', 'python', 'c', 'scala', 'groovy', 'haskell', 'perl', 'erlang', 'apl', 'cobol', 'go', 'lua'];
            $('#myTags').tagit();         
            $('#singleFieldTags').tagit({
                availableTags: sampleTags,            
                allowSpaces: true,
                singleFieldNode: $('#mySingleField')
            });
           });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="content">
            <p>              
                <input name="tags" id="mySingleField" value="Apple, Orange" disabled="true">
            </p>
            <ul id="singleFieldTags"></ul>
    </div> 
    </form>
</body>
```

Code behind

```
string queryString = "select * from SIB_KWD_Library ORDER BY Keyword asc";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["vConnString"].ToString()))
    {

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
        {

            connection.Open();

            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {

                while (reader.Read())
                {

                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SuggestionList))
                    {
                        SuggestionList += "\'" + reader["Keyword"].ToString() + "\'";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        SuggestionList += ", \'" + reader["Keyword"].ToString() + "\'";
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In browser source code all the tag keywords are visible. Something like

> var sampleTags = ['c++', 'java', 'php', 'coldfusion', 'javascript',
>   'asp', 'ruby', 'python', 'c', 'scala', 'groovy', 'haskell', 'perl',
>   'erlang', 'apl', 'cobol', 'go', 'lua'];

Please suggest any other way to do this.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What problem you are facing?

Comment: @Adil all the keywords are visible in browser source code. I want to hide this.and no. of keyword is up to 1 million.

Comment: In browser source code all the tag keywords are visible.....Yes because you are using them up...restrict it if you dont want to use them all

Comment: select * from SIB_KWD_Library ORDER BY Keyword asc ,Put some where,or top clause here

Comment: @ShekharPankaj thats why i post the question. for the suggetion for how do I hide these keywords , is any other way ?

Comment: Filter by keyword ,update your sql like....WHERE Keyword LIKE ''%'+feild.text +'%''

Comment: and from where i get the `feild.text` ??

Comment: [Have a look at this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11101231/jquery-tagit-autocomplete-fetching-json-list-via-ajax), rather than rendering your tags, I would [turn your asp code into a handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392413/asp-net-returning-json-with-ashx) and then make an ajax request to get the tags in json format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use `<%= this.SuggestionList %>` instead of `<%# this.SuggestionList %>`

**JS:-**

```
 <script>
        $(function(){
           var sampleTags = [<%= this.SuggestionList %>];
            //var sampleTags = ['c++', 'java', 'php', 'coldfusion', 'javascript', 'asp', 'ruby', 'python', 'c', 'scala', 'groovy', 'haskell', 'perl', 'erlang', 'apl', 'cobol', 'go', 'lua'];
            $('#myTags').tagit();         
            $('#singleFieldTags').tagit({
                availableTags: sampleTags,            
                allowSpaces: true,
                singleFieldNode: $('#mySingleField')
            });
           });
    </script>
```

**Edit**

**JS:-**

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://"+location.host + '/Default.aspx/GetKeywords',
            type: 'GET',
            datatype: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(res) {
                $('#singleFieldTags').tagit({
                    availableTags: res.d,
                    allowSpaces: true,
                    singleFieldNode: $('#mySingleField')
                });
            },
            failure: function(err) {
                alert(err);
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

**CS:-**

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static string[] GetKeywords()
    {
        List<string> lst = new List<string>();
        string queryString = "select * from SIB_KWD_Library ORDER BY Keyword asc";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["vConnString"].ToString()))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        lst.Add(reader["Keyword"].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return lst.ToArray();
    }
```

Simply replace the `lst` with your keywords returned from database.

Comment: That is okay but my query is not like you answered :(

Comment: @Gitz Write a ajax method to get the list from the server using WebMethod and inside success use your tagit code.

Comment: @wix kid that is what i am looking for. Actually  from direct call from code behind is easy but all the keywords are visible into the browser source code. i want to bind it directly from sql sever

Comment: @Gitz Please see Edit in my answer.

Comment: Okay !! i am trying :) i will let you know

Comment: thanks Working fine :) but how do i populate `SQL` values into the `List<string>`

Comment: Thank you so much @Wiz Kid. Now working Fine.But getting a little problem in every tag `Cross` button is not displaying.

Comment: I have one more question that the autocomplete list is going to very lengthy..is there any option for the scroll or top 15 result for that :)

Comment: `.ui-widget {
  height: 40px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}` change the height as per your need.

Comment: Sir i want to ask one more question - is it possible to modify this autocomplete to `SQL` Like Search ??

Comment: @GItz Didn't get your question completely?

Comment: Autocomplete text search is working with the `=` search.Means when I type `a` the result showing the words which starts from 'a'. and my query is when I type 'a' the result should be all the words contain the alphabet `a`something like `SQL Like Search `