# Success function after jquery plugin is applied (tag-it)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, tag-it

Im wondering is there any way to make some actions after the plugin is applied
For example,

```
$("#mytags").tagit({
    tagSource: function (request, response) {




    }
});
```

and I want smth like this:

```
$("#mytags").tagit({
    tagSource: function (request, response) {




    }
}, function(){
        $(#test).remove();
});
```

Comment: Can you provide more of your `tagSource` function?

Comment: tagSource function doesnt matter at all
It can be any function, I dont need a callback from tagSource func, I need callback for the successfully applied plugin

Comment: Why do you need a callback? Why can't you just call `$("#test").remove();` on the next line?

Comment: If you really need it in a chained manner (even though in your example it's only selecting one element), you could use `$("#mytags").tagit({}).each(function () { // Refer to 'this' for each element });`

Comment: I need a callback because:
tagIt transforms my div into tagIt block with input, I need to put a placeholder value on input, but I can do it only after successful plugin init

Comment: So my point is: is there anything asynchronous being done in `tagSource`? Like, is it making an AJAX call or something? If not, then there's no reason you can't just call `.remove()` on the next line.

Comment: Do either of these help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938802/trying-to-get-tag-it-to-work-with-an-ajax-call or https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/issues/13 . Like I said before, your code for your `tagSource` method would help, but hopefully those links can help

Comment: the thing is that tagSource success func is called when some actions are provided
and I need to do smth exactly after plugin is applied, no any other actions performed
and there's just no native success callback for jquery plugins from what I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a good look in the source code of the plugin and it doesn't provide such callback. I need it as you. In my case, it doesn't import the required attribute, so the required message appears floating completely lost on the page. I made a monkey patch. It's not perfect, but solved my case. I'll try to add this callback to tag-it and send it to github. Anyway, here is my dirty fix:

```
       var temp = setInterval(function()
       {
            if( $('.ui-widget-content.ui-autocomplete-input').length > 0 )
            {
                clearInterval(temp);
                $('.ui-widget-content.ui-autocomplete-input').doSomething();
            }
       }, 500);
```

**EDIT:** Better solution. As I've just said. I made an alteration in the code and I'm sending it to the main branch, you can see my version of the plugin here: https://github.com/kalkehcoisa/tag-it/blob/master/js/tag-it.js
It has a callBack "afterCreated" that is fired when the tagit finishes being applied. One example of how to use it:

```
            $('#singleFieldTags').tagit({
            availableTags: sampleTags,
            singleFieldNode: $('#mySingleField'),
    afterCreated: function(){ alert( 'test' ); },
        });
```

I hope this helps. ;)

Hey! The tag-it head developer answered me (https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/pull/215#issuecomment-26191461) about my pull request. The thing were far simpler than we thought:

> All you need is $('#myWidget').('create', function (event) { /* ... */
>   }); as is standard in jQuery UI. Perhaps an example in the docs is
>   necessary...

Developing and learning! ;P

Comment: Hi @Jayme. Nicely explained answer. I am getting an error when i try       $('#myWidget').('create',function(){
   alert("in");
}); is giving me an error "Unexpected token ("

Comment: Added create function inside the widget itself. Started working as expected. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score -2):

You need to discover plugin API for appropriate event. If you use [this one](http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it/), it has such event: `afterTagAdded (function, Callback)`.

Read [documentation](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/blob/master/README.markdown) for how to use.

Comment: Thanks, but thats not what I need.
Exactly what I need is:
1. Plugin applies to the div, sends whatever etc
2. After its done I need to hide/remove/do anythings else.
Is that possible?