# How to use jQuery.tagit() dynamically?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I'm trying to fetch designations from database using ajax and php and store those values in a javascript variable designations.
I'm trying to set the availabletags option of tagit() from this designation variable.

```
var tagThis = $(".tagit");
tagThis.tagit({
    tagSource: function(search, showChoices) {
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url: "/tags/search",
        data: { queryString: inputString },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            var assigned = tagThis.tagit("assignedTags");
            var filtered = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                if ($.inArray(data[i], assigned) == -1) {
                    filtered.push(data[i]);
                }
            }
            showChoices(filtered);
        }
    });
}
});
```

The drop down isn't getting produced when I change the type to POST.

Comment: Please check this post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938802/trying-to-get-tag-it-to-work-with-an-ajax-call

Comment: I referred the above code and was able to implement tagit dynamically but I'm not able to use tagit() with post. I want to the drop down to be based upon the value entered in the field.

Comment: Used get instead