# Building StackOverflow like tagging system

Tags: php, tagging

I am building simple blogging framework using PHP and MySQL, and on the add new-post page I want to add live tags (like StackOverflow when asking questions). I can't add tags directly to the database and link them to the current post because until clicking on Publish or SaveDraft there is no entry for current post.

Is there any way, I can tagging like StackOverflow and on clicking Publish or SaveDraft add them to database?

Comment: Yes, of course. They are just another bit of data you send from the browser to the server.

Comment: @andreapier — The question you linked to is about *styling* tags but this question is about *storing* them. They are barely related and answers for one do not apply to the other.

Comment: Why the close votes? The question seems very legitimate to me.

Comment: I am new here, and doesn't know about voting etc., but thanks for answering in few minutes, +1 to Stackoverflow

Comment: For future references check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519107/jquery-autocomplete-tagging-plug-in-like-stackoverflows-input-tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is immediatly assign an ID to the post (thus removing the ID problem), and have a "published" field that is 0 until the post is published.

In this way the tags are stored normally, as if the post were published, and the post is saved as a "draft".

Comment: thank you very much sir, One more question, what to do if user cancel that post without publishing or drafting after assigning temp. ID?

Comment: If you put a "cancel" button, then it's easy, just remove tags and posts associated with the temp ID. If the user just closes the page... well there it depends on your design. Either keep the draft for next time the user logs in, or delete all posts not published after n days (30? 60?)