# Tag Search using jquery as in stackoverflow Tags textbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to create a tag search/suggestion div as it is shown in stackoverflow at the bottom when I try to type a Tag and it gives me suggestion. I want to use JQuery UI. Can some one suggest me how to do it when I type in textbox. Any sample code of link please. thanks

Regards,
Dev

Comment: jQuery UI provides an autocomplete widget: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: @James: I need exactly like stackoverflow. autocomplete gives suggestions as list, I want it as popup with textbox.

Comment: you can allso have a look at http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/ , the only downside is that it is initialy written in coffescript however you can still go thru the js source but without any comments .

Comment: @ poelinca anything like this in Jquery UI ? How to customize it or write it in jquery

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set up jQuery autocomplete like stackoverflow's input field tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519107/set-up-jquery-autocomplete-like-stackoverflows-input-field-tags)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete)** is your way to go. You can configure it to look exactly the one StackOverflow has.

Comment: How can I customize/Configure the autocomplete ?