# textarea autosuggest for both @mentions and #tags

Tags: jquery, tags, textarea

I am working in a rails 3.2 application and i have a requirement to provide auto-suggest for a text area to fetch @mentions users and #tags in the same textarea.

To elaborate:
when a user starts typing @ab... the autosuggest should fetch users fron json is provide and when he types #ab it should suggest tags from json i provide.If there are no tags for the letters entered the new tag should automatically get added to the suggest list and get appended to the textarea on click action.

Please suggest some jquery option to enable thi feature in a textarea

Answer (score 6):

Here is another we just open sourced: [jquery-sew](https://github.com/tactivos/jquery-sew)

Answer (score 3):

You will love this one. this is your required library
http://podio.github.io/jquery-mentions-input/

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few good options listed here: [jQuery autocomplete tagging plug-in like StackOverflow's input tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519107/jquery-autocomplete-tagging-plug-in-like-stackoverflows-input-tags)

Of those, I'd recommend the tag-it plugin ( http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it/ ). It should be pretty simple to configure its autosuggest to do what you want.

As a side note, most of your options are probably going to use `<div>` instead of `<textarea>` tags, since textareas are really intended just for text.

---

Shameless plug: I've been trying to put together a jQuery tag-editor plugin with autosuggest myself, actually, and the code is pretty straightforward if you need to tweak anything: https://github.com/donmccurdy/input-tokenizer

Comment: These seem a little off-topic because they transform all text to tags and there is no free text input as the question requested...