# How to add a picture in textbox in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to create a widget like "Stack Overflow" Tag Field. How to add pictures with text in html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the HTML generated, the tags with background and images are not actually inside the text box.  Instead, the text box sits invisibly to the right and a new `<span>` is created every time the user enters a space or comma.

You could create one yourself, but it's probably easiest to use an existing plugin.  You can see some suggestions here:

[jQuery autocomplete tagging plug-in like StackOverflow's input tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519107/how-can-i-set-up-jquery-autocomplete-like-stackoverflows-tags-input-field)