# Tag autocomplete with PHP (like SO)

Tags: jquery, tags

Does a jQuery (preferably) plugin exist for tagging like on Stack Overflow? When you post a question, the 'Tags' field lets you type tags in.

I need something that will let you type in any part of a tag and x suggestions for this tag will be generated, as something like a dropdown menu. Another requirement is that when I type the next tag, more suggestions will be generated, and that when you click on a suggested tag, it finishes off the tag you're typing and doesn't just append it to the input field.

I've seen this being done on many websites but can't find any plugin to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set up jQuery autocomplete like stackoverflow's input field tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519107/set-up-jquery-autocomplete-like-stackoverflows-input-field-tags)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sounds like Tag-it. jQuery UI is a requirement. You can find the project and source code on Github: https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it

[image]

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for.