# Html button inside input text like Gmail

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

The new email from gmail use this kind of button on from field:

[image]

I'm thinking in something like that, but I have no idea how it can be done.

Is it possible to use it with jquery mobile?

Thanks advanced.

**[EDIT]**

Ok, I didn't know how to find it, so sorry for duplicate question.

But I have another question. In the examples It always transform the word in a Tag, but I want write a normal text just with 2 or 3 tags. Is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tag autocomplete with PHP (like SO)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10355826/tag-autocomplete-with-php-like-so)

Answer (score 4):

Yeah there is  great JQuery stuff for that. It works on mobiles fine aswell (tested by me many times)

Check it out here: 
[JQuery Tag-it!](http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/)

Comment: Thanks for the direct answer ^^

Comment: @cechinel no problem, does it work for you now or do you need more input?

Answer (score 1):

Try this plugin, This is what you need i think.

http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not a default form field, but a clever UI enhancement. StackOverflow uses this same technique for tagging your post, which you probably noticed :)

See: [Tag autocomplete with PHP (like SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10355826/tag-autocomplete-with-php-like-so)

Comment: Ohh really, It exactly the same question ^^
Thanks
Do you know if I can use it just in some parts? Like a normal text with just 2 or 3 tags?

Comment: Each jquery tagging plugin has its own options; I am sure one of the configurable options is the number of tags, so yes.