# LinkedIn style tagging when adding skills

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was looking online for good javascript tagging libraries. I was reading the following post: [jQuery autocomplete tagging plug-in like StackOverflow's input tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519107/jquery-autocomplete-tagging-plug-in-like-stackoverflows-input-tags)

But I'm afraid mine is slightly different design constraint. I would like it to be more liked LinkedIn when adding skills to ones profile..so it's not inline. Is there anything that is available online for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using tagit ( http://jquery.webspirited.com/2011/02/jquery-tagit-a-jquery-tagging-plugin/) and was able to customize it for my needs. Wasn't too difficult to do.