# Any open source tag editors, just like SO's?

Tags: javascript, user-interface

Looking for a UI element implementation that allows to select multiple items out of a predefined set, just like the tag editor we have here, below the question form on StackOverflow.

I don't even know what the proper name for such control is to google for it. Multi-select? Multi-edit?

Autocomplete (and jQuery Autocmplete) is not quite it because it selects just one item, although the tag editor does have autocomplete as an aid.

jQuery is OK although I prefer generic JavaScript that works on modern browsers: IE9+ and the rest.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

jQuery UI [Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) has [multi-select](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple) support.

Other than that, in no particular order:

- [Select2](https://github.com/select2/select2)
- [jQuery Tag-it!](http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it/)
- [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/)
- [TextExt](http://textextjs.com/)
- [jQuery Tags Input Plugin](http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/)
- [jQuery Tagit](http://webspirited.com/tagit/)
- [tagedit](http://tagedit.webwork-albrecht.de/)
- [jQuery Tokeninput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/)
- [FCBKcomplete](http://www.emposha.com/javascript/fcbkcomplete.html)
- [AutoSuggest](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin)

**Edit:** Just found another similar SO question. Take a look there also: [jQuery autocomplete tagging plug-in like StackOverflow's input tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519107/jquery-autocomplete-tagging-plug-in-like-stackoverflows-input-tags)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Miroslav. It's strange this UI element doesn't have a commonly accepted name. Also it's a shame they are all based on jQuery although I'm quite sure many won't work on older browsers due to advanced CSS etc. So if older browsers aren't support why use jQuery? Anyway, that was rather rhetorical :)

Comment: Well, we need to http://movethewebforward.org/ eventually :)

Comment: and anyway Internet Explorer (the elephant in the room here) _is_ supported for jQuery back to ie6 ! which is definitely < 1% of even ie users anyway today (2013).

Comment: A great library compatible with AngularJS is: http://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select

Answer (score 3):

[Chosen.js](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) is a simple clean library; it also allows multiple selects.

[image]

Comment: No support for server-side tags.  You'd have to download them all locally for this plugin, which is useless when there are tens of thousands of tags.