# In search of good Tagging library

Tags: javascript, tags

I am looking for a good tagging library. I wanted to have Ajax, autocomplete, and being able to store values and labels for each tag. I found a few promising ones, but I was not able to develop on top of it for my needs. The one I looked at extensively is below:

http://textextjs.com/

I was not able to submit value and label, it only accepts the label as the value. Is there any other library which would encompass what I was looking for? Or is there something I'm missing with the above library? I was reading the docs for it and could not get it accept label and value.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519107/jquery-autocomplete-tagging-plug-in-like-stackoverflows-input-tags#

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one. It's flexible and you can alter it for your own use. It has a cache facility too.

[jQuery tokeninput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/)

Comment: Is there a way to prevent people from typing a tag that is not suggested?

Comment: I did not see that in the documentation, otherwise looks good.

Comment: yeah you can take use of onAdd(builtin method)
A function to call whenever the user adds another token to their selections. In that function you can remove unwanted tags from the input box

Comment: Docs are on the same page down.. Its easy to use and has lot of flexibility.. Also demos are http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/demo.htm

Comment: After going in circles with bootstrap-taginput (+ typeahead + bloodhound), and then taggle, this solution Just Works.  Thanks!