# How to remove the values with jquery on deleting characters in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I have this code

```
<input type="hidden" value="[{"value":1,"label":"Emmoia Boently"},{"value":6,"label":"John Smith"}]" name="group[users][]" id="users">

<input type="text" value="Emmoia--Boently, John--Smith, " name="autocompleter_group[users][]" id="autocompleter_userss" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true">
```

Now my problem is the current javascript is adding the values from textbox to the hidden feilds.

But when i delete the text then it don't deletes from the hidden input fields.

So i want to do in jquery that when i start deleting the text in main textbox then the value gets deleted in the hidden input field as well.

just like we do in SO when we delete the tag characters in ask question page

Comment: Any code? How you add values and trying to remove them?

Comment: To start, you've got your quotes messed up in the example. Second, why not just re-set the hidden field's value to the current representation of the textbox. This would be much simpler than trying to parse out which value got deleted.

Comment: i am using jquery autocomplete plugin

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#autocompleter_userss").on("keyup", function() {
    $("#users").val($(this).val());
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y64Tk/)**

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** Seems like you're looking for a tag editor. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519107/jquery-autocomplete-tagging-plug-in-like-stackoverflows-input-tags) for exhaustive links :)

---

```
$('input#1').change(function(){
  $('input#hidden').val($(this).val());
});
```

Additionally, you could try some data-binidng libaries like [knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/helloWorld.html) among others.

Comment: its not that simple. In the hidden box i have the ids and text but in the text box i have only text , which i get via AJAX autocomplete call. I think i some how need to have cross button to delete the values

Comment: @volcano: Now I get your question. See my update. Try **[this one](http://textextjs.com/)** and [this one](http://levycarneiro.com/projects/tag-it/example.html) to check if you've found what you were searching :)