# jQuery autocomplete formula editor plug-in

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, tagging, formula-editor

The answer to this question is close to the ons given here: [jQuery autocomplete tagging plug-in like StackOverflow's input tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519107/jquery-autocomplete-tagging-plug-in-like-stackoverflows-input-tags)

However mine has a twist.

I'de like to allow entering "non tags" string.

I want to create a text field that allows the user to type formulas, based on available variables (our tags).
User should there be able to type something like "[Variable 1] x [Variable 2] / [Variable 2]".

What is in "[]" is a tag and should displayed differently that the rest of the strings.
Also, the actual value of the textbox would be slightly different. Something like "{{1}} * {{2}} / {{3}}".

I'm not asking how to do that (though also this sort of answer can be accepted), but if there is anything similar already available as a jQuery plugin.

I've tried to google and look here on SO, but I always end up on mostly the same kind of tagging plugin: maybe I'm using the wrong search string :)