# Gmail/Linked in style contact input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle

How can we handle a content-editable="false" element inside a content-editable="true" element on IE?

What I want to do is inser a span inside a content editable div. It works fine on Chrome, where if you backspace on the span which is content-editable="false", then the whole span is deleted.

On IE this displays very strange behaviour!

Any inputs?

Answer (score 1):

I found a really good library for exactly this sort of thing.

It's jQuery based so its just perfect!!

http://tagedit.webwork-albrecht.de/

Also, linking here to some more research:
[jQuery autocomplete tagging plug-in like StackOverflow's input tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519107/jquery-autocomplete-tagging-plug-in-like-stackoverflows-input-tags)