# Comma separated values in block

Tags: php, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery autocomplete tagging plug-in like StackOverflow’s input tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519107/jquery-autocomplete-tagging-plug-in-like-stackoverflows-input-tags)

I am working on a recruitment portal where languages are submitted with text box having comma separated values e.g English, Arabic, Frech

The values are saved in the database using explode, implode (having nothing with question, just to clearify)

I would like to make the textbox decorated like when some one press comma the previous word become a block with a close sign indicating to remove the word.

Example : Searching in deviantart, or tags in wordpress, tumblr

Comment: @TryingToImprove yeah dear, i was looking for the same solution. Thank you very much..

Comment: @Jai its done dear, i was looking for the same plug-in TryingTolimporve suggested.

Comment: Okay! great carry on plz. :)

Answer (score 0):

hummm if i am not wrong you want something called tags like in stackoverflow tags.
Yepee there is one plugins called tagit in jquery. links is as below.

http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it/

Hope this is the one that you are asking for.