# Javascript - tags, text and elements.

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I make a feature similar to one on this site. When you enter tags in a text field - when you type in a word and press space, the written word is made into a small grey box with the text inside and an X on the right side inside the box for removing the element if clicked.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519107/jquery-autocomplete-tagging-plug-in-like-stackoverflows-input-tags

Comment: Another way to go: 1) look at this script: http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/full.js?v=ee8dc25807f6; 2) search for `.tag-editor`; 3) use the code; ... 4) PROFIT!!!