# Bundle that integrates Javascript tag library with Sonata Admin Bundle

Tags: symfony, autocomplete, taglib, sonata-admin

I am working on a Symfony 2.3 application which uses Sonata Admin Bundle for it's backend. Is there any ready to use bundles that provides integration with any modern JS autocompleted tag library ([tags libraries examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519107/jquery-autocomplete-tagging-plug-in-like-stackoverflows-input-tags)) and Sonata Admin Bundle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use [GenemuFormBundle](https://github.com/genemu/GenemuFormBundle)

This bundle provides extra form : Captcha GD, Tinymce, Recaptcha, JQueryDate, JQueryAutocomplete, JQuerySlider, JQueryFile, JQueryImage

You should use `genemu_jqueryselect2_choice`, see [this demo page](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)

Hope this helps