# Django ManyToMany field using through with relational value

Tags: django

I have a model with many to many field, the field it linked through a table with Boolean value.

I got this in different scenario, lets take user as the main model, interest as the many to many field and user_interest model as the through model, inside user_interest I have a Boolean field which I want user to specify when selecting each of his many to many value,

At the moment am stuck trying to find an appropriate form interface to cater for my need, currently am using MultipleSelect widget which only show selection of interest, is there any example for field control that would allow me to choose the interest and specify the value of the Boolean field? If not, what is best practice to follow in my situation?

Best regards,

Update question with code samples

```
class Interest(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=200, )


class UserInterest(models.Model):
    interest = models.ForeignKey(Interest, )
    user = models.ForeignKey(getattr(settings, 'AUTH_USER_MODEL'), )
    join_mail_list = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class User(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  interest = models.ManyToManyField(Interest, through='UserInterest', related_name='user_interest')
```

Now based on the models above, when I try to create a ModelForm from User model, I will get interest as MultiSelect field which is perfectly correct. But, in my case, I want the form to collect user interests + for each interest if he wants to join_mail_list for that particular interest. Please advise?

Answer (score 0):

The question is kind of general, but I'd say that since it's a boolean field, instead of one multiselect field, you have two - one for "Things I'm interested in..." (True) and one for "Thing's I'm not interested in..." (False). Both fields would be multiselect from the same list of items, but the seperation allows the user to apply the boolean field without even noticing. Also, I strongly recommend jQuery UI autocomplete, seems like the best choice here.

**Updated answer:**

So seeing your code helps clear a few things. The way I would do it is like I suggested in the first place but with a little tweak.

Having a newsletter checkbox for each 'interest' is clumsy, because it requires the user to check the 'interest' twice - once because he's interested in it and once because he wants emails about it. So you have to automatically assume that the user *wants* to get an email for the subjects he is interested in, but allow them to prevent it if they want.

With that in mind, you build two long text inputs, and implement both of them with a tagging system ([here's a good one](http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/), here are [some more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519107/jquery-autocomplete-tagging-plug-in-like-stackoverflows-input-tags)). The first input is "I'm interest in", and the second is "I want to recieve emails about...". Then you add an event listner with jQuery that makes sure that for every tag added to the first input it is automatically added to the second one as well. Then, if the user doesn't want to get emails for a specific subject (or all of them) he can easily take it off the second input (which doesn't have any effect on the first one).

To give you an example, [here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ALpuv/18/) that shows how to make that happen with the chosen-jQuery library. I used Countries and Shipping because I had a pre-made list at the chosen library website, so I just copied it from there. As you can see, it's a pretty simple jQuery code, which you can easily applicate for any other tagging system (and many thanks to the fine Raúl Juárez who [helped me work that out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18432783/autofill-an-input-when-another-input-is-filled-using-jquery-chosen-on-both/18434286) myself):

```
$(".chosen-select").chosen({disable_search_threshold: 10});
$('#countries').on('change', function(e) {
    var selected = $(this).val();
    $.each(selected, function(index, value) {
        $('#shipping option[value="'+value+'"]:first').prop('selected',true);
    });
    $(".chosen-select").trigger('chosen:updated');
});
```

Comment: I just updated my question with sample code, I hope it will clarify further my question

Comment: updated my answer, hope it helps. If you want code examples too just ask =]

Answer (score 0):

I'll just assume that you want a list of all interests with a checkbox next to them.

Let's assume those models:

```
class Ressource(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Ressource2Village(models.Model):
    ressource = models.ForeignKey(Ressource)
    village = models.ForeignKey(Village)
    amount = models.FloatField()

class Village(MapObject):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

And this form:

```
class Ressoure2VilllageForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    # you would use a BooleanField
    value = forms.IntegerField()
```

Now you can create a formset (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/formsets/):

```
from django.forms.formsets import formset_factory
r2v_formset = formset_factory(Ressoure2VilllageForm)

# use boolean for your case, if you want to edit these values later use n2m to initialize value
# [{'name': r2v.ressource.name, 'value': r2v.value} for r2v in your_village.ressource2village.all()]
init_values = [{'name': r.name, 'value': 0} for r in Ressource.objects.all()] 
r2v_formset = r2v_formset(initial=init_values)
```

Which in your template will give you:

```
<label for="id_form-0-name">Name:</label><input type="text" name="form-0-name" value="Kohle" id="id_form-0-name">
<label for="id_form-0-value">Value:</label><input type="text" name="form-0-value" value="0" id="id_form-0-value"> 
<label for="id_form-1-name">Name:</label><input type="text" name="form-1-name" value="Eisenerz" id="id_form-1-name">
<label for="id_form-1-value">Value:</label><input type="text" name="form-1-value" value="0" id="id_form-1-value"> 
<label for="id_form-2-name">Name:</label><input type="text" name="form-2-name" value="Golderz" id="id_form-2-name">
[...]
```

The association to the specific user can be done during processing under consideration of his authentication details.

Displaying, validating and processing this should be pretty straightforward, feel free to ask follow up questions.