# Autofill an input when another input is filled using jquery chosen on both

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I was helping another user here on stackoverflow when I faced a problem - I explained how to solve something, but I couldn't get my code (that I wanted to add as an example) to actually work. I'm pretty new to jQuery, so even though I understand the basics and what can and can't be done, I still find myself struggling with simple tasks.

In this case, I am trying to create two input fields, both using a tagging system ([jQuery chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)). Both inputs have the same list of options, and I want that when you enter an item for the first input it automatically adds it to the second input as well. The idea is you can remove any item you want from the second list without affecting the first one.

You can see my attempts in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ALpuv/1/). I tried extracting the value from the first input and looping over it, but for some reason it doesn't really loop beyond the first item.

I also tried to apply the first item to the second list like so:

```
$('#shipping option[text='+value.value+']').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

and after the loop doing this:

```
$(".chosen-select").trigger('chosen:updated');
```

I knew this wouldn't work beyond the first item, but it didn't even work for that. I'm pretty confused at what I should do next. It's obvious that the chosen changes the input and it doens't behave like a usual one, but I can't understand how to work this out. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: In your jsFiddle `alert($(this).val())`, gives you an error, that's why you only loop the first item. `value.value` is also an error.

Comment: That's not true. Chrome console didn't show any errors, and even taking away that line doesn't change anything, it still only loops once

Comment: In my console appeared this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined`. The line with `value.value` didn't show any errors either (but it is an error since `value`, is now only a `String` object, and doesn't have a `value` property), I remove the alert line and change the `value.value` line with that in my answer, and all went fine.

Comment: I did forget a ; at the end of that line, but that's a fluke, it's not what caused the problem, and I'm still not sure what brakes the loop (doing an 'alert("hello");' also works only once no matter what). Anyhow, the entire code still isn't working, not copying anything to the second input (not even the first tag I enter)

Comment: Ok forget that, the loop works now. I mistakenly deleted the initial val() for the var selected. That was the problem. However, it still isn't copying the data to the second input (not with attr and not with prop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this line:

```
$('#shipping option[value="'+value+'"]').prop('selected', true);
```

Beware that if you select "United States" or "United Kingdom", they will show twice in `Chosen` plugin, since those options exist twice in your html, but you can use the `:first` selector to avoid this

```
$('#shipping option[value="'+value+'"]:first').prop('selected', true);
```

EDIT

Here is the code working: http://jsfiddle.net/rf90210/uZBXM/2/

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Also, I don't understand what's the difference from using attr - prop is just a different function, but there's no inherent difference that means it should work rather than attr... right?

Comment: Both approaches (`attr` and `prop`) work in this case (at leas in Chrome). There is complete explanation of the differences here: http://api.jquery.com/prop/. I'm adding a jsfiddle to my answer, so you can check it out working

Comment: Mmmm, that's weird, the fiddle in my answer is working for you?

Comment: YES! yours is working! I compared them both, and it seems I did "option[text=...]" instead of "option[value=...]". I didn't think about that, makes sense. Thanks Raul!

Comment: Not worked for me, i had it same as in fiddle it needed to update chosen like: $("#contactsList").trigger("liszt:updated").trigger('chosen:updated');