# Create input form to add/remove keywords

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make something similar as in stackoverflow where you add keywords.

I'm just stuck with the HTML part or javascript?

When a keyword is found an clicked, how do i make it fixed in the input field? Like in stackoverflow it becomes blue with a remove button next to it.

Currently the results are being showed underneath the `<input>`, in a new `<div>`.

```
<fieldset>
    <label for="title">Add keyword<label>
    <input class="input" type="text" size="30" onkeyup="searchFunction()" onkeydown="searchFunction()">
</fieldset>

<div id="livesearch"></div>
```

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far?

Comment: just right click on the StackOverflow tags implementation and click on "Inspect Element" to see how the HTML structure for it is implemented. You can use that with any autosuggest plugin like - http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Answer (score 3):

It's not a real `<input>` element. It's just looks like input. You should use regular `<div>` and append (for example) stylised `<span>` to it.

Try out this plugin for jQuery https://github.com/xoxco/jQuery-Tags-Input .
You can use jQuery.autocomplete.

I'm using this plugin in production and it's ok.

Comment: In the source code of stackoverflow I find `<input id="tagnames" name="tagnames" type="text" size="60" value="" tabindex="103">`

Comment: Here is generated source (after javascript execution) http://cl.ly/S0p6. And yes, there is real `<input>` tag too. And when you add something to tag list in `<div class="tag-editor" />` element, javascript changes value of real `<input>`. You can't see it in the source on my screen, but it's value is `hello wowo` http://cl.ly/S0mB

Comment: The same logic is in custom form elements, for example. When you want create custom `select` field, you just create dropdown list. And when user clicks on dropdown item, you manually (I mean in javascript) change value of real `<select>` (that is hidden, but exists in markup).

Answer (score 2):

Look back at this SO question:

[jQuery autocomplete tagging plug-in like StackOverflow's input tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519107/jquery-autocomplete-tagging-plug-in-like-stackoverflows-input-tags)

the dude that answeres suggested

([demo](http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it/examples.html)) https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it

and much more. check it out you might find a solution that suites you the best!

Comment: I'm not using jQuery but I'll find a way out, thanks

Comment: For those interested in a non-jquery example, see my answer below

Comment: The demo is down and the plugin itself hasn't been updated since 2014. That was a good answer, but it's no longer one, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "easy" way to do it, you will need more then just a `<input>` to achieve this kind of behavior.

However, there are some good plugins **using jQuery** (don't know any made with plain javascript) which already made this:

[TextExt](http://textextjs.com/manual/examples/tags-adding.html)

[TokenInput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/)

[VisualSeach](http://documentcloud.github.io/visualsearch/#demo)

Answer (score 0):

Little late to the party *but* I created one as a React component. The underlying code is plain javascript (no jQuery), so should be easy to decipher.

[sterlingwes/react-taginput](http://github.com/sterlingwes/react-taginput)

See the `taginput.jsx` file for an idea how it works.