# How to Create Bounding Box with Possible Deselect after Space of Each Word Entered in Textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to provide functionality where a person would enter a word into a textarea using HTML/JQuery/Javascript (doesn't have to be a textarea if it can't be), then on pressing the spacebar, the word would be bounded and a 'x' would show next to it so that it can be removed.

Like this:
[image]

Apologies I am not sure what to call such an element / control.

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: I believe this is what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519107/jquery-autocomplete-tagging-plug-in-like-stackoverflows-input-tags

Comment: Thanks for the link! I eventually used Select2 found [here](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)

Answer (score 0):

**something like this**

html

```
<div id="box">
    <ul>
        <li><input type="text" id="type"/></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

jquery

```
function closer(){
    $('#box a').on('click', function() {
       $(this).parent().parent().remove(); 
    });
}
$('#type').keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {//change to 32 for spacebar instead of enter
        var tx = $(this).val();
        if (tx) {
            $(this).val('').parent().before('<li><span>'+tx+'<a href="javascript:void(0);">x</a></span></li>');
            closer();
        }
    }
});
```

this adds when enter is pressed, so it will work like `lord of the rings` instead of `lord` `of` `the` `rings`. change `e.which == 13` to `e.which == 32` if you want spacebar to trigger it.

it will still need css changes to make it look exactly how you would like, this is just an example of how it works.

made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/bjBQZ/

Comment: Hi there, this worked, but I eventually made use of Select2 found [here](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)