# How does Stack Overflow submit its tags along with the form?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to submit a form when the button is clicked and then redirect as usual. The problem is I created my own `<select>` mechanism using JavaScript and CSS so the `<option>`s will not be submitted unless I use AJAX (which I want to avoid to prevent form resubmission).

So, how does Stack Overflow (this website) submit their tags with the use of a regular submit button? Can I use a similar method to submit the chosen option when the submit button is clicked?

Comment: Why would you create a "select mechanism" when everything that exists serves the correct purpose well? We don't have a crystal ball, you will need to provide some code to allow people to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Popnoodles Because of 'looks'. If I create my own I am able to customize it as I like something not possible with a regular `select`.

Comment: Select would be underlying, and the appearance dealt with secondarily. Putting appearance before function will cause you numerous avoidable headaches.

Answer (score 5):

You're over-thinking this.

Open up your browser's debugging console, load up whatever DOM visualizer it contains, and find the input element with the id "tagnames". That's how tags are submitted.

[image: using the DOM inspector in Firefox]

Now, there's [a bunch of fancy stuff going](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100669/feedback-wanted-improved-tag-editor) on that makes it look a bit more interesting and easier to use, but at the end of the day when you submit a question on SO the tags are just a space-separated list (or comma-separated, if you prefer) of strings. Those are then parsed out server-side and mapped to the relevant information in the database.

So that's how Stack Overflow does it. That doesn't sound at all like what you're after though. If you want to let your users select tags from a list of some sort, then just make sure the selected values end up in *some* sort of proper form field - they'll then be submitted along with the form.

#### See also: [jQuery autocomplete tagging plug-in like StackOverflow's input tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519107/jquery-autocomplete-tagging-plug-in-like-stackoverflows-input-tags)

Answer (score 2):

Create `<input type="hidden">` elements on the fly using JavaScript. They'll be submitted with the form.

Comment: Is that what StackOverflow does?

Comment: Why don't you investigate how Stack Overflow does it?

Comment: @Popnoodles I tried, there's quite a bit of code to look at and maybe someone already knows. You still haven't provided an answer just more questions, but thanks.

Comment: No I haven't because this is not a valid question. Google jquery tags.

Comment: No, this "forum" is for helping people who get stuck on a particular issue within something they are developing, who provide enough code to reproduce the problem and don't ask questions about how to do something in general.