# Implementing search bar in website for searching with tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've this [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ponnus/56ta95b9/1/).

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">    
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-xs-12">
        <div class="input-group user-search">
            <div class="input-group-btn country-search">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <span id="search_concept">Select Country</span> <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#contains">India</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#its_equal">UK</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#greather_than">US</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#less_than">Pakistan</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#all">All Countries</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group-btn city-search">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <span id="search_concept">Select City</span> <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#contains">Mumbai</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#its_equal">Chennai</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#greather_than">Kolkata</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#less_than">Delhi</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#all">All Cities</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="search_param" value="all" id="search_param">         
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="x" placeholder="Search term...">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="fa fa-search"></span></button>
                    </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am using bootstrap for this. Now, I want to implement a search using tags just like adding tags on stack overflow when asking questions (with auto complete). Can anyone help me in doing this?

Comment: This is much, much too broad. You've provided a bunch of HTML and asked us how to write the backend logic for a complicated search engine. This is not a code-writing service.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. As mentioned - we wont' write your code for you (you have to pay one of us for that) ;) Here, we expect you to have a go at it yourself - even if it's just writing up the pseudocode. Then, when yo get stuck on one point, come back and ask a question about that particular problem, and include the code you've tried and the error you're getting... and we'll help you get over that hurdle.

Comment: Try something and post your code of what was your approach to do the same.

Comment: Thanks for the advice... :) . I searched again and found this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519107/jquery-autocomplete-tagging-plug-in-like-stackoverflows-input-tags That was what I needed. Only front-end. I'll do back-end myself. I think my question was misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bhavuksuthar/vc7yc2a7/) of `typehead` in `input` tag for `bootstrap`

I hope thats what you mean.

Comment: Thanks for that. This is what i meant....

Comment: @ponnus happy to help and accept the answer if it was useful for you