# How do I implement tagging in web app post? Like how questions on stackoverflow have tags?

Tags: html, sql, tags

So I have a form where a user can post a project. He fills the fields and submits so far. However what I would like is to use a tag system where instead of writing a string of skills needed for the project, they should be tags. Then implement a tag based search. Kind of like here on stackoverflow you can search questions based on tags. I'm not sure what to google or what kind of question I am looking for. Maybe someone can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous jQuery plugins that do this.  For a comprehensive list of them, see [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519107/jquery-autocomplete-tagging-plug-in-like-stackoverflows-input-tags).  I personally like [Tag-it!](http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/examples.html), which is probably the most popular one.