# Autocomplete for tags

Tags: php, jquery, html, arrays

I searched for the auto complete tag style that stackoverflow uses and I got an answer [from this question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519107/jquery-autocomplete-tagging-plug-in-like-stackoverflows-input-tags) and I also followed this [github link](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it) from the question which I got my answer. In the github [example.com](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/blob/master/examples.html) here is the jQuery code below:

```
        $(function(){
        var sampleTags = ['c++', 'java', 'php', 'coldfusion', 'javascript', 'asp', 'ruby', 'python', 'c', 'scala', 'groovy', 'haskell', 'perl', 'erlang', 'apl', 'cobol', 'go', 'lua'];
       --------------------------
        $('#allowSpacesTags').tagit({
            availableTags: sampleTags,
            allowSpaces: true
        });
        
    });
    //the html for input box
    <form>
        <p></p>
        <ul id="allowSpacesTags"></ul>
    </form>
```

And that is the array containing the auto completion. But the problem is that I want my own auto completion array to be from my database which I want the images, names and usernames of the users to show up as the auto completion and when a user is clicked, the username goes into the input box. Let's assume the html output from my database will look like this for each user:

```
<div><img src="userimg" />user full name<br>username</div>
```

But if I pass this code in the auto completion array the images won't show up instead  if I press the < key, the html code comes up as the auto completion. Please how do I make the auto completion array to contain images and html codes also and when a user is clicked, only the username goes into the input box. Anyone with a better Idea?

Comment: People are more likely to assist you if you include the code on the post, instead of using the links.

Comment: @Jhecht.... The codes are so broad and many so I think it will make my question look bulky. But I think the actual necessary code is the jQuery array code which I showed in the question

Comment: I'd much rather have a bulky looking question with all the information I need than one where I have to go and collect each piece individually.

Comment: @Jhecht..... edited. With the jQuery code

Comment: the `availableTags` function can be located [here](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/blob/master/js/tag-it.js)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Is this really a problem related to jQuery or HTML?