# Django taggit integration with frontend (auto-complete and auto-suggest)

Tags: python, tagging, django-taggit, django-tagging

I'm looking for a django app that provides a form-filed with taggit integration and a front end JS tagging library as mentioned here: 
[jQuery autocomplete tagging plug-in like StackOverflow's input tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519107/jquery-autocomplete-tagging-plug-in-like-stackoverflows-input-tags)

Do I have to implement this myself or is there an existing django app that integrates django-taggit with a front-end tagging library.

Ideally I would want auto-suggest and auto-complete. Admin integration would be nice.

This will be useful for others too since every body wants SO like tagging or more advanced tagging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following options for implementing auto-complete in `django-taggit`.

https://github.com/Jaza/django-taggit-autocomplete

https://bitbucket.org/fabian/django-taggit-autosuggest

https://github.com/20tab/django-taggit-live

https://github.com/gnotaras/django-taggit-autocomplete-modified

Some of these libraries seem to be old and broken on the latest django versions.

I also found an alternative library to `django-taggit` called `django-tagulous` which has auto-complete integrated.

Note: It doesn't have Django 1.11 support yet in the main branch.

A nice bonus is it uses Select2 JS library and has admin integration.

https://github.com/radiac/django-tagulous

Comment: django-tagulous still needs to include support for Django 3.0+, would use them otherwise

Answer (score 0):

For Django 2.0 and newer versions, maybe you would like to check https://pypi.org/project/django-autocomplete-light/

It's very well documented for many use case and, working with compatible packages are also including on https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/