# search tags like stackoverflow?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

how do you code a search box like the one in Tags where you enter a tag name and all tags are showing immidiately without you press enter.

can someone link me a script or tutorial for that. is it javascript or jquery? does it involve ajax?

and does it search in the database for tags? or is it searching through a xml file with tags?

Comment: Check out this SO post: [How does StackOverflow’s ‘tags’ textbox autocomplete work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/282282/how-does-stackoverflows-tags-textbox-autocomplete-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this JS library, http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

Comment: How can you submit the multiple selected values for the link you provided?

Comment: @xjshiya You should be able to since multiple values are selected.