# Jquery autocomplete with jquery 1.4

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-autocomplete

Referring to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282282/how-does-stackoverflows-tags-textbox-autocomplete-work) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188442/whats-a-good-ajax-autocomplete-plugin-for-jquery). I'm trying to implement tag search for my blog/website something similar to SO tag system using [jquery autocomplete plugin](http://view.jquery.com/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/demo/), I'm using jquery 1.4 latest version so I'm not sure whether it works with it or not, I've used this plugin before once. So without further jibr-jabr here is my html for autocomplete :

```
<input id="post-tags" class="ac_input" type="text" autocomplete="off" value="" name="post_tags"/>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){

 function findValueCallback(event, data, formatted) {
  $("<li>").html( !data ? "No match!" : "Selected: " + formatted).appendTo("#result");
 }

 function formatItem(row) {
  return row[0] + " (<strong>id: " + row[1] + "</strong>)";
 }
 function formatResult(row) {
  return row[0].replace(/(<.+?>)/gi, '');
 }

 $("#post_tags").autocomplete("http://localhost/tags/filter/", {
  width: 260,
  selectFirst: false
 });

 $("#clear").click(function() {
  $(":input").unautocomplete();
 });


    });
  </script>
```

I'm sure my php part is ok, it works like this when I manualy type the url `http://localhost/tags/filter/p`

I returns the following :

```
php (1)
asp (1)
```

Meaning all tags containing p, for now I have only these two. My question is, what am I doing wrong, I'm really stuck on this one, I've changed things around so many times now I can't think of anything new I'd like to do. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use post instead of get, when using get `/` gets erased but when using post complete thing is passed so the autocomplete needs some adjustments(extra one line) here it is :

```
$.ajax({
                type: "post", // This is the new line
                // try to leverage ajaxQueue plugin to abort previous requests
                mode: "abort",
                // limit abortion to this input
```

Everything worked like a charm now..