# I want to implement something like the tagging system used on Stack Overflow. How?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Is there a name for the method that stackoverflow uses to select tags for questions, ie, typing multiple entreies in a long text field and selecting from ajax-loaded options?

I want to do this with emails, where each email added appears in a list, but maintains hidden form fields underneath?

Is there a jquery plugin that does this?

Comment: This requires both client and server elements, so there is no "jQuery plugin" since it only handles client-side code.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/q/282282/584420

Answer (score 1):

I have used Tagit and personally like it: http://jquery.webspirited.com/2011/02/jquery-tagit-a-jquery-tagging-plugin/

Demo link here: http://webspirited.com/tagit/#demos

Answer (score 0):

Checkout another thread about tag plugins, there are quite good examples:

[Open source jquery autocomplete tagging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9385935/open-source-jquery-autocomplete-tagging/10284098#10284098)