# Open source jquery autocomplete tagging

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, open-source, tagging

I really like http://www.devthought.com/projects/jquery/textboxlist/ for autocomplete, but I was wondering if there is an open source version.

I also really like http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin.

Here's another question on Stackoverflow that is pretty useful [Facebook style JQuery autocomplete plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191807/facebook-style-jquery-autocomplete-plugin)

Comment: The jQuery UI site has a demo that gets you 90% of the way there: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this Rails example based on Tag-it! and autocomplete:

- Working example: http://tag-it-autocomplete.heroku.com/
- Source code: https://github.com/makaroni4/tag-it-autocomplete

Answer (score 3):

I really Like this one: http://jcesar.artelogico.com/jquery-tagselector

Comment: I really like this one. I also want to be able to create new tags if there isn't a record in the AJAX call.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a modified version of the jquery ui demo I linked:

http://jsfiddle.net/6DwRQ/

It needs some css fixes and dynamically re-sizing of the input element as tags are added, but that's basically all there is to it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another good one:

http://webspirited.com/tagit/?page=tagit#demos